# Prove that $0$ divides $a$ if and only if $a = 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $0\mid a$ if and only if $a = 0$.

I am a first year maths student and I'm looking for a well-constructed proof for this statement that uses the fact that..

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. $a\mid b$ if there exists some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies $b = ka$.

Comment: **Hint** $\ \ 0\mid a\iff \exists n\!:\ \underbrace{0\cdot n}_{\large 0} = a\iff 0 = a\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***CASE 1***

Suppose that 0 divides a. By the definition of ‘divides’, there is an integer
q such that a = 0q, so that a = 0q = 0, as desired.

***CASE 2***

Suppose that a = 0. Then we have that a = 0(1), so that 0 divides a, as desired

UNDERSTOOD